# Highlighting with grep doesn't work in Xterm

Tags: kubuntu, colors, grep, xterm, tail

I've got a problem with Xterm.

When I use the command

```
tail -F example.log | grep -a -i -e 'examplestring'
```

in Xterm the "grepped" strings aren't highlighted in red like they would be in the normal terminal.

How can I fix this? Google didn't help me very much.

Answer (score 4):

Open **terminal** ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ) and type

`export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'`. This will highlight the matched pattern of `grep`

To set it to **Red** color use: `export GREP_COLOR='1;31'`

For more color options check out this [page](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#colors)

[image]